# How to set thread priority pthreads on Mac OS

Tags: c++, pthreads

I've found:

```
pthread_setschedprio()
```

here: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_setschedprio.3.html

But I can't find any valid values for thread priority. For Windows I've found very clear possible value, like:

```
THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL
THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL
THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL
```

but for Mac OS I didn't found anything. I can't use Cocoa NSThreads class, I need to use POSIX threads.

Do you know how to set thread priority pthreads on Mac OS?

Comment: have you tried any integer value?

Comment: I would just like to give the obligatory caution that most people who use thread priorities or think they should use them really don't want to and will just make things worse by using them. They don't make the higher priority threads go any faster, and they introduce all kinds of potential subtle problems such as [priority inversion](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/mbj/mars_pathfinder/mars_pathfinder.html). Instead, just code your threads to only do the work you want done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK `pthread_setschedprio()` doesn't exist on macOS. You can only set the priority of a thread when you create it using `pthread_setschedparam()`.

And as for priority, see documentation for `pthread_setschedparam()`:

> Valid thread priorities (accessed via param->sched_priority) must be within the range returned by the `sched_get_priority_min(2)` and `sched_get_priority_max(2)` system calls.

Answer (score -4):

While I certainly agree with the comment above about avoiding modifying thread priorities or scheduling to solve an issue, you may want to start by reading the man page for pthread_getschedparam which discusses scheduling, and shows some values for min/max priority settings under OS X.  Then, rethink your problem again, and don't use thread priorities to solve it.

Comment: There are legitimate reasons to set the priority of a thread. (That's why the function exists.) Saying "read some documentation, then don't do it" is fine as a comment, but it isn't an answer.